# Which brain disorders cause better second language learning?

Tags: learning-psychology

I heard that people with some types of synaesthesia may have some advantages for learning second language. I don't know it is true or not. which kind of brain disorders cause better second language learning especially in adults?

Comment: I'd exercise caution in grouping synaesthesia with disorders. From talking with people who experience it, it doesn't seem to fit into the category of a disorder.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  "state of the mind", " kind of brain", etc.